# "ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?" On homebrew

Tags: python, django, virtualenv, homebrew

This is a typical problem but I couldn't find any solution in other threads.

Here's my setup:
MacOS Big Sur -> homebrew -> python3.9
I am running in a virtual environment, I've also manually de~ and activated it several times. I've checked `wsgi.py`. All requirements are installed properly. Here's what brew says about pythonpath:

> > % brew link --overwrite python@3.9
> > Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1
> > To relink, run:
> > brew unlink python@3.9 && brew link python@3.9`

Same error again

> > % brew unlink python@3.9 && brew link python@3.9
> > Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1... 24 symlinks removed.
> > Linking /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.7_1... 24 symlinks created.`

I've tried doing what it suggests and un~ and linking python. Still no luck.
That were all I could find on SO. Maybe I'm missing something? Or is there a way to analyze the problem I'm not aware of?

Comment: I believe you are running a command using python, try to execute `python3`

Answer (score 0):

Based on Shreeyansh Jain's reply to the original post. Indeed, that's something I didn't do. I've actually checked python versions as well:

```
% python -V
Python 3.9.7
% python3 -V
Python 3.9.7
```

Don't let this confuse you. Running `python3` instead of `python` despite seeming lack of difference is what I was missing. Hope it helps someone =)